# How to replace ARN in dashboard body with something that doesn't include accountId?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework, serverless

I am creating a CloudWatch dashboard with Serverless:

```
  PublishingDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
      DashboardName: publishing-dashboard-${self:provider.targetStack}
      DashboardBody: ${file(./Dashboards/fetchDashboard.js):publishingDashboard}
```

fetchDashboard.publishingDashboard looks like this:

```
module.exports.publishingDashboard = async (serverless) => {
  let file = await fsPromises.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'publishing-dashboard.json'), 'utf-8');
  file = file.replace(/{{TARGET_STACK}}/g, serverless.variables.options.targetStack);
  file = file.replace(/{{REGION}}/g, serverless.variables.options.region);
  return file;
};
```

A widget I want to display is causing me problems:

```
    {
        "height": 6,
        "width": 3,
        "y": 0,
        "x": 9,
        "type": "metric",
        "properties": {
            "metrics": [
                [ { "expression": "SEARCH('{AWS/States,StateMachineArn} StateMachineArn=*{{TARGET_STACK}}productName* MetricName=ExecutionTime', 'Maximum', 86400)", "label": "", "id": "e1", "region": "{{REGION}}" } ],
                [ "AWS/States", "ExecutionTime", "StateMachineArn", "arn:aws:states:{{REGION}}:123467890:stateMachine:First-StepFunction-{{TARGET_STACK}}productName", { "id": "m1", "label": "First", "visible": false } ],
                [ "...", "arn:aws:states:{{REGION}}:123467890:stateMachine:Second-StepFunction-{{TARGET_STACK}}productName", { "id": "m2", "label": "Second", "visible": false } ],
                [ "...", "arn:aws:states:{{REGION}}:123467890:stateMachine:Third-StepFunction-{{TARGET_STACK}}productName", { "id": "m3", "label": "Third", "visible": false } ],
            ],
            "view": "pie",
            "region": "{{REGION}}",
            "stat": "Average",
            "period": 300,
            "legend": {
                "position": "hidden"
            },
            "title": "Execution Time",
            "labels": {
                "visible": false
            },
            "liveData": true,
            "setPeriodToTimeRange": true,
            "stacked": false
        }
```

The body references the accountId but the serverless parameter doesn't include it. Is it possible to either get rid of the accountId in the body or get the account id to be included in the serverless parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference ID of you account using `${aws:accountId}`. This is described in [Referencing AWS-specific variables](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#referencing-aws-specific-variables) part of Serverless Variables documentation.

When resolving variables with JavaScript function, it receives an object as a parameter with a function called `resolveVariable`, which can be used to resolve provided variable string. See [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#with-a-new-variables-resolver). Looking at your code, I suspect you're using [deprecated resolver](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#with-a-legacy-deprecated-resolver) not supporting this feature. You must upgrade by declaring `variablesResolutionMode: 20210326` in `service` section of your YAML.

Function may also access configuration properties through variable resolution process. Full example:

```
module.exports.publishingDashboard = async ({resolveVariable}) => {
  let file = await fsPromises.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'publishing-dashboard.json'), 'utf-8');
  file = file.replace(/{{TARGET_STACK}}/g, resolveVariable('opt:targetStack'));
  file = file.replace(/{{REGION}}/g, resolveVariable('opt:region'));
  file = file.replace(/{{ACCOUNT_ID}}/g, resolveVariable('aws:accountId'));
  return file;
};
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks like it could resolve my issue. But I haven't been able to get it to work. I have put `variablesResolutionMode: 20210326` at the top level of the serverless file as I have found in examples. I have updated serverless to `2.43.1` which I think should support the new resolutionMode. Yet the `serverless` parameter does not have the property `resolveVariable`